# sencha touch - nestedlist - store all the fields' values of "activeItem of nestedlist"

Tags: sencha-touch, nested-lists, sencha-touch-2

i have a panel which should show the "description" field of "currently activeitem of nestedlist". nestedlist uses the model having fields:

1. id
2. text
3. description

when user taps on any item of nestedList [on selectionchange OR itemtap&backtap], i want to change description in the panel with description of "currently activeItem of nestedList".

Is this possible?

thanks for any help/solution/pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem I had today, and no solution had been found with a nested list, because no single field can be taken from a Ext.data.TreeStore. One solution could be that you have lots of "if-function 'do with all the ID's and then you give each ID a text. But that's not good.

I've decided to make a simple list.
if you want I can show you my solution for the simple list

ps.: I use Sencha Touch 1.1

Update:

```
    NotesApp.views.NaviList = new Ext.List({
        fullscreen: true,
        flex: 1,
        layout: 'card',
        scroll: false,
        useToolbar: false,
        itemTpl: '{text}',
        store: store,
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function (obj, idx, el, e) {
                var record = this.store.getAt(idx);
                var tle = record.get('text');
                index = record.get('index');
                NotesApp.views.notesListContainer.setActiveItem(index, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

description:

My App has the name: "NotesApp".

"notesListContainer" is a Container where all my List are displayed. "index" is an ID that I get from the store and the calls list.

Now when you tap on my NaviList you set a new ActiveItem in this Container.

Comment: could you show animation onItemTap and onBackTap ? (like nestedlist shows sliding animation)

Comment: App.views.'YOURCONTAINER'.setActiveItem('YOUR ID FROM THE CARD', { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });

Comment: i am not following the mvc architecture. can u suggest me something for non-MVC architecture? List name is "myList".

Comment: See my Update. I hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for the reply. I also tried using **simple list** with one **Ext.button**(back button in case of nestedlist). On **itemtap** and **buttonclink**, i change list's content by 
`var t = new Ext.data.Store` and `list.setStore(t)`.

Please let me know if there is any other better option to do it.